# Poor Quality Image attachment in Android

Tags: android, image, attachment

i was capturing image in android application.Then i am getting that image path and sending that path as a string to email function. In MIME Mail i was attaching that file as `DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(path);`

My Code is...

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CAMERA_IMAGE);
```

Activity to get Path...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //image.setImageBitmap(null);

        //Uri return from external activity
        URI = data.getData();
      //  text1.setText("Returned Uri: " + orgUri.toString() + "\n");

        //path converted from Uri
        convertedPath = getRealPathFromURI(URI);
       // text2.setText("Real Path: " + convertedPath + "\n");

        //Uri convert back again from path
        uriFromPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(convertedPath));
        Log.e("HAAAAAAAAAAAIIIIII", uriFromPath.toString() + "\n");
    }

}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    //This method was deprecated in API level 11
    //Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            this,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    int column_index =
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Passing Image Path as String to Email

```
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(path);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the documentation @
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

You have to pass pass an extra `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to not be given a scaled down image.

Comment: In My Code .. Where I need to use?